# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null

Tags: jquery, javascript

Выдает ошибку -

> auto.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null

```
function getvalues () {
  $.post("/autoisk/getvalues.php", {
    name: selectedcompany,
    summma: $("#summma").html(data)
  }, function(data) {
    $('#resultat').html(data);
  });
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: @dwib, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @dwib, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В строке **summma: $("#summma").html(data)** переменная **data** очевидно лишняя.

Answer (score 1):

Хорошо бы сказать, какая из этих строк - 43-я. Вероятно, что какого-то из элементов с `id` равным `summma` или `resultat` не существует.